# How to return NULL in an Autofac registration?

Tags: c#, exception, autofac

Is there a way to return null with autofac? I get a exception if I do this.

In some cases I cant resolve a object and should return null.

```
m_builder.Register < IMyObject > ((c, p) => {
  //do something

  if (...) {
    //cant create/resolve object (error case)
    return null;
  } else {
    return new IMyObject();
  }

}).InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

Is there a build-in way to do this with autofac?

Edit:
I want to return null. Or do something else to inform the user that the creation was not successful. If I return null this exception will be thrown:

DependencyResolutionException:

> A delegate registered to create instances of 'IMyObject' returned
>   null.

Stacktrace:

> at Autofac.Core.Activators.Delegate.DelegateActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>
>   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1
>   parameters)
>   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.b__0()
>   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id,
>   Func`1 creator)
>
>   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() 
>   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope
>   currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration,
>   IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>
>   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration
>   registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext
>   context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) 
>   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext
>   context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext
>   context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
>   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext
>   context, Parameter[] parameters)
>   at RestApi.Controllers.MyApiController.CreateEntityContext() in
>   C:...

Comment: What is the exception message, inner exception, stack trace?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, returning NULL in a registration will always throw an exception. For some ideas on how to handle that, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11486759/540663).